# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near )

Tags: mysql

I am running into this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE  username='admin'' at line 1

I am trying to edit/update the profile, in the members area, everything works fine when registering, but when updating profile, the error comes up.

```
Table structure for table `tb_users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `bankname` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `actname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `actnum` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `acttype` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `weeklygoal` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `notify` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `manager1` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `referer` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `state` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `visits` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `referals` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `referalvisits` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `money` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `paid` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `joindate` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lastlogdate` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lastiplog` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `account` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `adcode` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `ip` (`ip`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tb_users`
--

INSERT INTO `tb_users` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `ip`, `email`, `bankname`, `actname`, `actnum`, `acttype`, `phone`, `weeklygoal`, `notify`, `manager1`, `referer`, `state`, `visits`, `referals`, `referalvisits`, `money`, `paid`, `joindate`, `lastlogdate`, `lastiplog`, `account`, `adcode`) VALUES
(1, 'admin', 'mypassword', '41.220.68.244', 'example@email.com', 'MainstreetBank', '23994949', '384847448', 'savings', '76789', '50000', 'nothing to say', '<b>Account Manager</b>', '', 'Ebonyi', '0', '0', '0', 'N500.00', '0.00', '1408514315', '1408514336', '41.220.68.244', 'premium', '');

/
```

Comment: Show us your original query which produces this error

Comment: The error code is not related to the create table.. its something else.

Comment: Show us the query you try to attempt in relation with this table. Otherwise we can't give you an answer.

Comment: Error message clearly mentions **WHERE username=**. You haven't shared the query that contains that string.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE username='admin'' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE username='"

It looks like you missed some quotes in your `SELECT` query.

Comment: I edited the question with the full error, please check

Comment: @makanjuolacaleb : No, you didn't. The code you post isn't the query who throws the error.

Comment: I am trying to edit a profile, in the members area, everything works fine when registering, but when Updating profile the error comes up.

Comment: WHO WILL HELP ME! Please

Comment: Can you provide your QUERY to DB? If you edit profile it shoul start from "UPDATE TABLE `tb_users`... WHERE..."

Comment: WHERE username='admin'' at line 1